# Hibernate: detached object modification

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I faced the problem, that I've already solved, but still can't expain the reason of it. The problem linked with object modification in detached state.

**What I have:**

Person -> (one-2-many) -> Address. Person has a lazy-list of addresses (**with orphanRemoval = true**).

**What the problem:**

When I clear *person's* addresses in detached state, old addresses still present in DB, even after reataching *the person* to the new session, **updating** and commiting. But **after merging all works fun**.

**What the question:**

What change *merge(person)* compared to *update(person)*?

**What I do:**

***In the first session:***

```
person.setAddresses(addressesList);
transaction1.commit();
session1.close():
```

***In detached state:***

```
person.getAddresses().clear(); //addresses collection declares with orphanRemoval = true option. So all addresses should be deleted after collection is clear. Is it true in detached state?
```

In the second session:

```
session2.update(person); //Person person2= (Person)session.merge(person);  - solve the problem
person.getAddresses().add(newAdress);
transaction2.commit();
session2.close();
```

**ADDITION:**

"Use update() if you are certain that the session does not contain an already persistent instance with the same identifier. Use merge() if you want to merge your modifications at any time without consideration of the state of the session. In other words, update() is usually the first method you would call in a fresh session, ensuring that the reattachment of your detached instances is the first operation that is executed." (c) from [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html).

*But my session2 is fresh. Whan in such case merge() method could change?*

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_sequence", sequenceName = "sq_person")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private List<FileInfo> files;
    //getter & setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Address {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "adress_sequence", sequenceName = "sq_adress")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long adressID;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
}
```

Comment: Is profile same as person? Did you implement equals() and hashCode()?

Comment: Yeah. I corrected this error

Comment: Did you implement equals() and hashCode() in Person class?

Comment: No, I didn't implement.

Comment: That may be the issue.

Comment: I don't understand why. Explain me, please!

Comment: Just a guess but when I read this "...already persistent instance with the same identifier..." I think about how gets the identifier and if makes a call to .equals(). Anyways, it is a good practice to have equals and hashCode. See: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode

Comment: I check in debuger. equals() and hashCode() methods is never called

Comment: I suppose that orphanRemoval with lazy collections doesn't work in detached state + may be exists some cross-session cache

Comment: can you provide Person/Address and full save/update code?

Comment: You already have the full code, by exception of achiving detached state: it achives with help of serialization/deserealization (String s = convertObjToJson(person); person = convertJsonToObj(s)). All cide proceedes in one single method.

Comment: entities code in addition